# Finitely axiomatized conservative set theories

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is it possible to finitely axiomatize any theory conservatively by some generally applicable trick?

Do the Gödel and Bernays trick work for any set theory like ZFC+large cardinal axioms?

Is it possible to finitely axiomatize some conservative extension of set theory without introducing a new sort (the class sort) or an additional predicate like Gödel's sethood?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by Godel's set-hood?.....

Comment: I mean his 1st-order (basic) predicate in the formulation of Bernays-Gödel-Neumann set theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann–Bernays–Gödel_set_theory, while Bernays used different sorts of variables.